# How do I doxygen-document unnamed parameters of a function?

Tags: documentation, doxygen

With doxygen, I'm used to write

```
/**
 * @brief blah blah
 *
 * @param foo description of foo
 * @param bar description of bar
 * @return description of the return value
 */
int f(int foo, unsigned bar);
```

But what if I don't name one of the parameter? :

```
int f(int, unsigned bar);
```

How can I document this parameter when I can't refer to it by name?

Comment: Other than make a textual reference it is, as far as I know, not possible. What is the objection of having a name in the definition / prototype?

Comment: @albert: When you do not use the parameter, it is (sort of) customary to leave it nameless.

Comment: Yes I know, but why having the argument in the first place (historical / compatibility is a good reason though). What is the reason for documenting the not used argument?

Comment: @albert: It might be important to understand why this function is invoked with an extra supposedly-useless parameter, e.g. (in other functions invoked similarly this is used for XYZ, but in this function it isn't because reasons."

Comment: I think in that case here it should be also 'XYZ' (or 'dummy_xyz') and the description should explain why it is present.

Comment: @albert, If a parameter is unused, adding the name causes compiler warnings (complaining ... the parameter is not used), so not naming it at all is a frequent code style, when binary compatibility must be preserved.

Comment: @MarcAlff I think there are directives in that case that can hide these warnings.

Comment: @albert, technically, yes, this can be fixed, but consider the bigger picture: as long as adding doc is changing only _comments_, adding doxygen doc is seen as low risk, and fixing doc in a project even very late is accepted. Now, if adding doc changes _code_, no matter how insignificantly, and if this causes a build break with -Wall -Werr, selling off doxygen to a dev team is going to be much harder, causing pushback. On top of that, some people do not like to write doc, and will use any excuse (look, it can break he build) not to write any. So, having to name the param is unfortunate.

Comment: @MarcAlff my opinion about this is a bit differently (but that was already clear). Unfortunately documentation is still a last minute action and often badly maintained, actually a good coding practice would be to write documentation (and think about the implementation) before starting to code. The reason for having unnamed parameters is clear (a.o. overloaded functions). Feel free to submit to an enhancement issue in the doxygen issue tracker (https://github.com/doxygen/doxygen/issues/new) with a suggestion how to fix it without breaking the established doxygen builds of others.

Comment: Small thing I could not write in the previous comment: it is always possible to write something in the detailed description (or in a `\note`) about the missing parameter.

Comment: @albert, to clarify, I was explaining the rational to keep unnamed parameters. I would also just use a note myself. The following request was filed just to document a possible solution https://github.com/doxygen/doxygen/issues/6926 : "@param 1 This was for foo, unused", since there is one. Regards.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Doxygen does not currently (July 2020) implement this functionality. However, a feature request has been opened on the Doxygen GitHub issues page for it:

[#6926 Feature request: doc for unnamed parameters](https://github.com/doxygen/doxygen/issues/6926)